# regex to extract anchor tags from html text Flex

Tags: regex, apache-flex

Im using this. specifing boundaries `<a` and `/a`

```
var regex:RegExp =  /<\b([a]) \w+ \<\/([a])\b>/g;
var test:String = "some text that starts and <a href="abc.com">Click Here </a>ends with same";
var a:Array = test.match(regex);
```

My problem is it is only find single word between `a` tag  if we have more words or special characters in between it will not match. can anyone  Solve it?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid HTML?

Comment: really... can anyone solve it? i refer you to this entertaining bit of insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx Expression:

```
/<\s*h2[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*h2>/g
```

Heading1

i have heading tag 
you can put anchor tag in expression and try it might help. I havent tested i used this long time ago.

Comment: I dont know much about regex so can you explain me each notations in answered regex `/<\s*h2[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*h2>/g` what it does?

Comment: I would like you to refer to this link http://geekswithblogs.net/brcraju/archive/2003/10/23/235.aspx which is good to know how different notations works in regex i am not an expert in regex.